# Should I use std:: and boost:: prefixes everywhere?

Tags: c++

In my C++ code I don't use the declarations `using namespace std;` or `using namespace boost;`. This makes my code longer and means more typing. I was thinking about starting to use the "using" declarations, but I remember some people arguing against that. What is the recommended practice? std and boost are so common there should be no much harm in that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I use `using namespace` only in C++ files, not in headers. Besides, using hole namespace not needed in most of times. For instance, you could write `using boost::shared_ptr` or `using std::tr1::shared_ptr` to easily switch between `shared_ptr` implementations.

Sample:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

int main()
{
    cout << "test" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, unfortunately -- it doesn't :( g++ doesn't support it.

Comment: Strange to hear that. It is standard.

Comment: Sorry! That's just me being dumb -- I kept the "namespace" part. It works as advertised.

Comment: This approach has the added advantage that by putting the using statement immediately after the include, it documents what is being used from that include file. In this case we immediately see that iostream was included to use cout.

Comment: A third option is to use typedefs which may be helpful for other reasons:  typedef boost::shared_ptr<foo*> foo_ptr_t;

Answer (score 16):

`Using namespace ...` was not invented just for fun.

If you have a good reason to use it, then do so (and the frequent use of stuff from these namespaces is the exact good reason). Don't listen to fanatics who tell you everything they don't want to do for obscure reasons themselves is evil.

However, a good source for reasoning in these regards is C++ FAQ lite:
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/coding-standards.html#faq-27.5

I have read it and still decided to use it like you want to. Now you can make your own informed decision :-)

Comment: +1 for the link to the FAQ. Personally, I write `std::` prefix. Only when the tediousness becomes too high (i.e. `boost::filesystem` namespace) I write `using namespace`, but only inside a function definition, never in file scope.

Comment: For longer namespaces you could use `namespace fs = boost::filesystem`, and later refer to `boost::filesystem::path` by typing `fs::path`.

Answer (score 7):

My own rules are:

- in header files, all names are explicitly qualified e.g. `std::string`, `std::cout` etc. at their point of use
- in source files, place using clauses for the commonly used names at the top of the file eg. using `std::string;`
- never use `using namespace xxxx;` in production code.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that the code is cluttered with ::std:: prefixes is indeed annoying when reading the code.  However, you want to know what namespace a symbol was in as easily as possible...

Now isn't that the IDE's job?

As long as my IDE doesn't support 'view short typenames', I'm leaning towards `using` declarations for commonly known symbols (i.e. the STL, boost, ...).  Readibility first!

Comment: How does removing the namespace increase readability? I think that just loses information...

Comment: English:When English:you English:repeat English:the English:same English:thing English:all English:the English:time English:it English:just English:becomes English:noise.

Comment: @GMan: the "English:" example is just what you would be doing if you put your code full of std::vector iso plain vector.

Comment: Depending on the information you need, you want to see different things: if I want to see the control flow, I'm not interested in types, let alone namespaces of types.

Comment: The "English" example is misleading though. The comment is already in the "english namespace, so there's no need for the prefix. Similarly in C++, you only use the prefix when you're accessing something from a *different* namespace. If you want to use a spanish word in an english sentence, I think a spanish:: prefix is fair enough. It tells the *english* reader which language dictionary he should look in to find the definition of this strange new word he just encountered.

Comment: @jalf: it's not in the english namespace: it's a sentence constructed with English words, just like a program constructed from std classes.

Comment: @dave: It would be much more readable if the English:: namespace would be highlighted in a different color. Good editors/IDEs does just that.

Answer (score 4):

One factor to keep in mind is that the `std` namespace is named this way to make it short. A `std::` prefix is only 5 characters, hardly the end of the world. That's unlike .NET's namespaces like `System.Collections.Generic`. It is designed to be easy to type.

For that reason, I usually just type out the `std` prefix. Boost isn't too bad either, so I usually type that out too.

I usually alias the sub-namespaces (`boost::filesystem` for example) to something shorter (`namespace fs = boost::filesystem` for example)

Using typedefs liberally helps too.
And if I need to reference a type often, I might just add a `using` for it.

But I generally try to avoid `using`'s in headers especially, and when I do use them, I prefer to put them at function scope to avoid polluting the actual namespace.

C++ offers a lot of tools that let you avoid having to specify the namespace, without polluting the global namespace.

Comment: It is just 5 characters, but it accumulates: boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::pair<double, double> > > payment_periods;

Comment: I would use typedefs for that case

   typedef std::pair<double, double> period;
   typedef std::vector<period> periods;

   boost::shared_ptr<periods> payment_periods;

Answer (score 1):

In header files, yes. That is because using "using std::name_of_std_member;" or using "using namespace std;" in a header file will cause all other files which include that header file to see the symbol in the global scope, thus defeating the purpose of namespaces. In source files, however, it is perfectly ok to use "using namespace std;" to make the symbols of that namespace available with the "std::" prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I use `using namespace` *only inside function bodies*. In header files, I always qualify the namespace explicitly.

Seldom (when copy pasting a colleague's code for mockup), I use `using namespace` at namespace scope (ie. for the whole translation unit).